# AngularJS Form Submit not firing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router

I cannot seem to work out why the following isn't triggering a form submit.

1. form has `ng-submit="vm.processForm()"`
2. `<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitjobform_submit" class="btn btn-danger">`
3. `ng-controller` has the `processForm` function
4. Its an embedded view using `ui-router` but I don't think that matters so long as the view itself works I would at least expect it to trigger a page submit.

Any advice gratefully appreciated!

--Simon

**HTML code:**

```
<section class="mainbar">
<section class="matter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="widget wviolet">
                <div ht-widget-header title="{{vm.title}}"></div>
                <div class="widget-content user">
                    <form name="submitjobform" novalidate ng-controller="SubmitJobController" class="form-horizontal" id="submitjobform" ng-submit="vm.processForm()">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input ng-model="formData.name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngRequired="true" >
                                <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.name.$error.required">
                                    Required!</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <textarea  ng-model="formData.description" class="form-control" name="description" ngRequired="true" >
                                    </textarea>
                                    <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.description.$error.required">
                                        Required!</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="formData.category" class="form-control" name="category" ngRequired="true" >
                                        <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.category.$error.required">
                                            Required!</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Assignee</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <select ng-model="formData.assignee" class="form-control" name="assignee" ngRequired="true" ng-options="name.name for name in vm.names">
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.assignee.$error.required">
                                                Required!</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitjobform_submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="widget-foot">
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </section>
```

**Controller code:**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('app.submitjob')
.controller('SubmitJobController', SubmitJobController);

SubmitJobController.$inject = ['logger'];
/* @ngInject */
function SubmitJobController(logger) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Complete the fields below and hit submit to create a new job';
    vm.names = [
    {name:'Kishori', role:'child'},
    {name:'Zen', role:'child'},
    {name:'Simon', role:'parent'},
    {name:'Nam', role:'parent'}
    ];


    activate();

    function processForm() {
        logger.info('awesome!');
    };

    function activate() {
        logger.info('Activated Submit Job View');
    }
}
})
();
```

Thanks for your help,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems with your code:-

1) It seems like you are trying to use controller As syntax, in that case you need to specify that in your `ng-controller` directive. i.e do: `ng-controller="SubmitJobController as vm"`. As it seems like you are trying to access the properties prefixed with `vm` (if not you must set that on the `$scope`)

2) Input type `type="button"` will not trigger form submission, you need to change it to `type="submit"` in order for submit event to get triggered on the form and which is what `ng-submit` directive listens to. So do:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitjobform_submit" class="btn btn-danger">
```

3) You need to set the function on the controller instance (since you are using controller as, otherwise it needs to be set on the `$scope` with appropriate change on the view), i.e do :

```
this.processForm = function() {
  logger.info('awesome!');
};
```

instead of

```
function processForm(){...}
```

4) You need to create the module (once) before getting it. In your case change:

```
 angular.module('app.submitjob').controller...
```

to

```
 angular.module('app.submitjob', []).controller...
```

**Demo**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.submitjob', [])
    .controller('SubmitJobController', SubmitJobController);

  SubmitJobController.$inject = ['$log'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function SubmitJobController(logger) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Complete the fields below and hit submit to create a new job';
    vm.names = [{
      name: 'Kishori',
      role: 'child'
    }, {
      name: 'Zen',
      role: 'child'
    }, {
      name: 'Simon',
      role: 'parent'
    }, {
      name: 'Nam',
      role: 'parent'
    }];


    activate();

    this.processForm = function() {
      logger.info('awesome!');
    };

    function activate() {
      logger.info('Activated Submit Job View');
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section class="mainbar" ng-app="app.submitjob">
  <section class="matter">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="widget wviolet">
          <div ht-widget-header title="{{vm.title}}"></div>
          <div class="widget-content user">
            <form name="submitjobform" novalidate ng-controller="SubmitJobController as vm" class="form-horizontal" id="submitjobform" ng-submit="vm.processForm()">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input ng-model="formData.name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngRequired="true">
                  <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.name.$error.required">
                                    Required!</span>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea ng-model="formData.description" class="form-control" name="description" ngRequired="true">
                  </textarea>
                  <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.description.$error.required">
                                        Required!</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" ng-model="formData.category" class="form-control" name="category" ngRequired="true">
                  <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.category.$error.required">
                                            Required!</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Assignee</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select ng-model="formData.assignee" class="form-control" name="assignee" ngRequired="true" ng-options="name.name for name in vm.names">
                  </select>
                  <span class="error" ng-show="submitjobform.assignee.$error.required">
                                                Required!</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitjobform_submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="widget-foot">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. 2 and 3 were relevant. 1 and 4 were not as they were handled elsewhere in the code. I neglected to mention i am using John Papa's Hottwel generator which initializes the modules outside of the controller definition and also uses ui-router which sets up the Controller as statement.